# Factorization of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

if  $f(x)=Ax^2+B x-6$ has $x+1$ as a factor and  if $f(1/2)=-75/8$, find the values of $A$ and $B$ and the zeroes of $f(x)$.

Find other factors of $f(x)$.

Comment: what did you try? try to use factor theorem

Answer (score 2):

$x=-1$ is zer0 of $f(x)=Ax^2+B x-6$ thats mean
$$A-B-6=0$$
$$A/4+B/2-6=-75/8$$
or
$$A-B=6$$
$$2A+4B=-27$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$(x+1)(Ax-6)=Ax^2+Bx-6$$
$$Ax^2+(A-6)x-6=Ax^2+Bx-6$$
hence 
$$A-6=B$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $(x+1)$ is a factor of $Ax^2+Bx-6$ than $f(-1)=0$, use this and $f(1/2)=-75/8$ and you have two equations with the unknowns $A,B$. Solve the system and find the two unknowns.